# how to import excel to sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

We have an excel file more than 500 columns. And we have to import this file into MS SQL SERVER 2008 table. But it only accepts 255 columns.

Can anyone suggest a way to import/copy excel data to sql table ?

Comment: https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/data-pump/

Comment: _what_ exactly only accepts 255 columns? SSIS import wizard? BCP? Bulk Insert? What makes you think this? If you get an error, post it.

Comment: @Nick, when I import excel records to sql server it only take first 255 columns of excel sheet. While my excel sheet contains more than 500 columns. And I don't get any error on that. I just need to import all columns of excel sheet to sql table (MS SQL Server 2008 R2).

Comment: _what_ are you using to import? What tool? There are many tools.

Comment: @Nick, I am using SQL Server Management Studio to import the excel file.

Comment: Are you using right click / import?

Comment: @Nick, yes I am using right click to import.

Comment: The prevailing suggestion seems to be to export from Excel to CSV and import the CSV (as text) as it will handle that many columns. How did you get a file that big anyway?

Answer (score 3):

```
  please go through below link and follow the steps 

    https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

    While using  the Import wizard,  Click on Edit Mappings on the "Select Source Tables and Views" page of the wizard,  check the Type, Nullable, and Size columns for each source column. And must and should  mapping should be done properly
```

Comment: Also to enhance the tutorial maybe read up on the official post on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms140052(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try bulk Insertion?

You can able to move excel data into SQL Server using bulk insert command below.

```
BULK INSERT table_name FROM 'C:\Directory\excelfile.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR='\t',ROWTERMINATOR='\n', ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000)
```